# Writing msUnit tests for asynchronous procedures

Tags: c#, asynchronous, vs-unit-testing-framework

If you call the `Start()-Method` of a `MyClass-Object` the Object will start sending data with the `DataEvent`.

```
class MyClass {

    // Is called everytime new Data comes
    public event DataEventHandler DataEvent;

    // Starts de Data Process
    public void StartDataDelivery()
    {
    }

}
```

How do I write a Test for that functionality if i can Guarantee that the `DataEvent` will be Invoked at least three times during a fix time period.

I haven't done any asynchronous Unittests yet. How is that done, assuming that someone else needs to understand the test later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSTest hasn't had any serious updates for some time and I don't see that changing.

I'd strongly recommend moving to xUnit. It supports async tests (just return a Task from the test and `await` to your heart's content), and is used by many new Microsoft projects.

Comment: Thank you. Ill discuss this.

Comment: Further to this, if you add the xUnit Visual Studio NuGet package, your tests will appear in the VS test panel.

Comment: Ah.. thats nice.. ive read about that in the introduction on github.. richard, thanks alot